# Show changes after a DOM refresh

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Is it possible to highlight changes in the DOM after each AutoRefresh? What are some different approaches?

Comment: you mean the newly added elements through ajax or so ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maintain a separate class with required colors and whenever you add a element to dom on ajax, give this class to that element.

```
$('#yourid').load('new.html', function() {
  $("#id").addClass("newcolor");
  $
});
```

Comment: I was thinking of it the opposite way... if the page is doing a refresh, update previously viewed content to a "viewed" class... Your way would probably be adding less code though as only new items would have to be tagged.

Comment: @don , yeah , if you are adding elements to the dom through ajax , we can easily achieve what OP wants, we have various ways to find the div or table and just give a class...